# Using old-style comment in Preview 7.0

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

My group at work writes a lot of papers, and as a result we all proofread for each other.  However, some people like to print out the documents and edit by hand, while some prefer to edit electronically (myself being the latter).

Before upgrading to Mavericks and Preview 7.0, I noticed that the previous version of Preview in Lion had a very nice feature for annotating documents.  When I wanted to add a comment, a sidebar would appear with an area for me to write in, and a line drawn to the point where the correction is required.

Now, however, I cannot seem to find this function.  What is worse is that adding a Note places a small icon over the text which then expands to the full note.  This is fine if everybody is editing electronically, however those who print the paper only see that little icon.  For us, this renders Preview pretty much useless throughout the group.

Is there a way in 7.0 to use the feature I'm talking about?  I am hoping that I am just too unfamiliar with Mavericks/Preview7 and that the feature wasn't removed.  Otherwise, I'm going to need to find another app to replace Preview for editing documents.

Comment: You can copy the Preview.app from an older machine onto a new machine. Rename it to keep the original Preview.app. This is how I got some features back as well.

Comment: Hmm, that's a shame.  I'll see if I can find one.

Comment: Ok, so I did that, however it won't let me execute the previous version, saying that I can't use it with my current version of OSX.

Comment: Darn. This trick works on 10.8, not 10.9. Sorry for the hassle. Shame on me.

Comment: No worries.  I came up with a solution.  I highlighted the offending text, added a number, and wrote my comments in a separate text file.